# How to get facet.query results only, using solrj?

Tags: faceted-search, facet, solrj, solr

I'm trying to get results of a facet query using solrj, but it seems it doesn't matter whether I add the facet query or not. I get the same document list anyway.

So this query returns the same document list...

```
  query.setQuery(searchString);
  query.setFacet(true);
  query.addFacetField("CATNAME_STR");
  query.addFacetQuery("CATNAME_STR:" + facetName);
```

...with this query

```
  query.setQuery(searchString);
  query.setFacet(true);
  query.addFacetField("CATNAME_STR");
```

Only difference is I can get number of documents that matches the facet query with `response.getFacetQuery();`

I was expecting it to work like

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=*%3A*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&facet=on&facet.field=CATNAME_STR&fq=CATNAME_STR:Erasmus
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

By the way I'm using Solr Version 3.1.0 and solr-core-3.1.0

Comment: Can you run fiddler or something to see what the actual request to solr looks like?

Comment: @Aaron D - It seems like a handy tool but is there a linux equivalent of it. Also Firebug gives pretty good idea about headers too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out `fq=CATNAME_STR:Erasmus` does not mean `query.addFacetQuery("CATNAME_STR:Erasmus")` but instead `query.addFilterQuery("CATNAME_STR:Erasmus")`